# Catching Event from module

Tags: vb.net

I have function for send email in one module where I have declared my custom event:

```
Public Module myModule
    Public Event emailCompleted()
```

In that module I have function which are triggered when sending email is finished:

```
Private Sub SendCompletedCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Error Is Nothing Then
        RaiseEvent emailCompleted()
    End If
End Sub
```

All of that is working good, as expected.

Problem is that I don't know how to catch that event in my main program which call sendemail function.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only raise events from within a class and handle them outside that class:

```
Public Class myModule
    Public Event emailCompleted()
    Private Sub SendCompletedCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        If e.Error Is Nothing Then
            RaiseEvent emailCompleted()
        End If
    End Sub
```

and in your calling code module:

```
dim WithEvents myModuleObject as MyModule

Sub HandleEvent() Handles myModuleObject.emailCompleted
...
```

Comment: I CAN raise an event in module without error, but can't catch it outside. Anyway, thanks, I will reconstruct a program to get that working with class.

Comment: Yes, you *can* raise an event in a module, but it can't be caught.  You need a class variable declared `WithEvents`, and for that you need a class.

Comment: Got it working: Dim WithEvents se As New sendSMTP. Can't work without NEW keyword. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, you would need to set the class variable to an instance of the class, otherwise it contains `Nothing`.  You don't need a `New` instance if you have an instance created elsewhere, but if you don't have that, then, yes, you need a `New` instance.